# Getting Deadlock error (ORA-00060) while running application in jmeter (multiple user)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, jmeter, deadlock, database-deadlocks

I am trying to test my application in jmeter for measuring multiple user performance.

While executing my script, I am getting an oracle exception in between of the process as follows :

```
[org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-/0.0 .0.0:8081-38) ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource
```

Now I am not sure for which table/operation this error is occuring, also tried with increasing parameters like `INITRANS` and `PCTFREE` from its default values for all the tables.

My queries are :

1. what could be the root cause of this error ?
2. How can we get the exact table for which this deadlock is occuring ?

Thanks.

Comment: Does the error come with a stack trace?  If not can you modify the code/log settings to get the stacktrace, that will give you a good idea of where the problem lies.

Comment: Well, the error is coming without stacktrace at my jBoss Console : 17:01:28,599 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-/0.0
.0.0:8081-38) ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource

Comment: Have you turned up the hibernate logging levels?

Answer (score 1):

This type of error creates a trace file in the trace file directory. Check the created trace file as it explains why the deadlock is happening. If you have problems reading the trace file, upload the trace file.